# Javascript Regex for TeX enclosed by $$

Tags: javascript, regex, tex

**Regex Experts!**

Considering we have the following text, I'm attempting to find a REGEX to detect all `TeX` expressions enclosed by two `$$`s.

```
Select the correct answer:
  a) 10 % = $$\frac{1}{10}$$.
  b) 33 % < $$\frac{1}{3}$$
  c) 2 % = $$\frac{2}{100}$$,
  d) 9 % < $$\frac{1}{9}$$
  e) 5 % = $$1+\frac{1}{5}$$
  f) 1 % = $$0.05 - \frac{1}{5}$$
```

So far, what I have come up is:

```
/^\${2}[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/ ?]*(\${2}|[\n\r]| )$/g
```

which, as you might have anticipated, shamefully isn't working! Here are a few issues I have: first, I am having difficulty to detect `\frac` or for that matter `\`. Although I have added `\\`, that still fails. Second, I am having problem with the fact that `$$` could be followed by `space`, `newline`, `,` or `.` So even if I specify my expression to look for `$$` at the end, that still won't catch many of cases.

I know I am not the first person who has ever attempted this so please share your thoughts or recommendations. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/9kFSZp/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Looks like it's working. Can you please make an answer so I can accept that? I am still testing but looks like it's the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `^\${2}[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/ ?]*(\${2}|[\n\r]| )$` pattern is too verbose. Instead of whitelisting all possible chars there can appear in betweeb double dollar symbols, you may assume there may be any char there.

You may use

```
/\${2}.*?\${2}/g
```

Or - if there can be line breaks in between (which I doubt):

```
/\${2}[\s\S]*?\${2}/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9kFSZp/1/).

JS demo:

```js
var rx = /\${2}.*?\${2}/g;
var str = "Select the correct answer:\n  a) 10 % = \$\$\\frac{1}{10}\$\$.\n  b) 33 % < $$\\frac{1}{3}$$\n  c) 2 % = $$\\frac{2}{100}$$,\n  d) 9 % < $$\\frac{1}{9}$$\n  e) 5 % = $$1+\\frac{1}{5}$$\n  f) 1 % = $$0.05 - \\frac{1}{5}$$";
console.log(str.match(rx));
// => ["$$\\frac{1}{10}$$","$$\\frac{1}{3}$$","$$\\frac{2}{100}$$","$$\\frac{1}{9}$$","$$1+\\frac{1}{5}$$","$$0.05 - \\frac{1}{5}$$"]
//or, to get what is inside

var rx_extract = /\${2}(.*?)\${2}/g;
var m, results = [];
while (m=rx_extract.exec(str)) {
  results.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(results);
// => ["\\frac{1}{10}","\\frac{1}{3}","\\frac{2}{100}","\\frac{1}{9}","1+\\frac{1}{5}", "0.05 - \\frac{1}{5}"]
```